# how to open up socks/SSH on different network interfaces?

Tags: networking, iptables, socks, tunneling, iproute

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i usb0 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 8080 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

// route the traffic with mark 1 to myusb0 table

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table myusb0
```

ip route ls

```
192.168.0.0/24 dev usb1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.136  metric 1 
192.168.3.0/24 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.182  metric 1
```

ip rule ls

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32762:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup myusb0 
32763:  from 192.168.3.0/24 lookup myusb0 
32764:  from 192.168.0.1/24 lookup myusb1 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

ip route ls table myusb0

```
default via 192.168.3.2 dev usb0
```

ip route ls table myusb1

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev usb1
```

// open up socks on port 8080

```
ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:8080 root@192.168.3.182
```

// check if it works

curl --socks5 192.168.3.182:8080 ip.appspot.com

```
channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack.
```

I have two Internet connections from two different ISPs and I would like to open up a proxy/socks5 on each one.  I thought it would make sense to associate each interface with a port number so that we can manage the connections.

I've created two routing tables (`myusb0` and `myusb1`) for each device (`usb1` and `usb0`), then marked the traffic based on the port number (e.g. on port `8080` I mark it 1) and route the traffic on that mark to the specific table (`myusb0`). Then I tried to open a socks5 on that IP and tried it locally but for some reasons it doesn't work.

Once I get it working locally I think I should open up the socks in a reverse manner so that I can make it available to the remote server(s) that need to use it.

Any idea why it's not currently working and how I should fix it? For some reasons I think the socks connection is trying the default gateway from the main table which is not set instead to follow the port `8080` mark rule and try the myusb0 table. I'm using Ubuntu (latest version).

Should be mentioned that both ISPs provide dynamic IPs

**Edit**

As I suspected it seems that the traffic to port 8080  is not being routed  (nevermind the socks issue) but I don't know why

```
 curl portquiz.net:8080 
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```